# Grub giving Error 2: Bad file or directory when I try to locate the kernel

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I'm trying to boot a VM with grub-legacy and I'm getting a grub prompt.

If I run `root (hd0,0)` it says `Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83`, but then if I do `kernel /`<kbd>TAB</kbd> it says `Error 2: Bad file or directory type`, same for (hd0,1). Any idea?

I've tried find /boot/grub/stage1 and it says file not found.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out `/boot/grub/device.map` didn't match my layout, it had `(hd0)` as `/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/vda`. Fixing this, then booting it with a rescue CD and running through `grub-setup` again fixed it.